# How do I get separate options in my select box instead of a whole string

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

This is my problem:
[image: problem]

As you can see I only get one option in my second select box, the whole array as a string of the value that i get as a value from the first select box and store it in state.

This is my code:

```
class Courses extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedCourse: []

    };
    this.onSelectCourse = this.onSelectCourse.bind(this);
}
onSelectCourse(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    this.setState(
        {
            selectedCourse: [e.target.value],
                //[e.target.id]: 
            //}
        },
        () => {
            console.log(this.state);
        }
    );
}

render() {
    const { selectedCourse } = this.state;
return (
    
     <div><div class="center"><h1><b>Course</b></h1>

         <table>
             <tr>
                 <td><tr><label>NAME*</label>
                 </tr>
                    <tr><select onChange={this.onSelectCourse}>
                        {CoursesList.courses.map((item, i) =>
                            <option key={i} value={item.dates}>{item.name}</option>
                        )}
                     </select></tr>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <tr>
                         <label>DATE</label>
                     </tr><tr>
                        <select>
                            {this.state.selectedCourse.map((item) =>
                                <option key={item}>{item}</option>
                                )
                            }
                         </select></tr>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>

     </div>
         <div class="cmpdiv">
             <div class="center">
                 <h1><b>Company</b></h1>
                 <table>

                     <tr>
                         <td>
                             <tr><label>NAME*</label>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <input class="inpName" type="text" />
                             </tr>
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
                 <table>
                     <tr>
                         <td>
                             <tr><label>PHONE*</label>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <input class="inpPhone" type="text" />
                             </tr>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <tr>
                                 <label>E-MAIL*</label>
                             </tr><tr>
                                 <input class="inpEmail" type="text" />
                             </tr>
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <button type="submit"><b>Add a </b>company</button>
                     </tr>
                 </table>

             </div>

         </div>
```

How can I list the dates as different options in my second select box?

This is my .json file from which I get the values:

[image: This is my json file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like below

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    courses: [
      {
        name: "JS",
        dates: ["2017-01-01", "2017-10-31"],
        id: "1",
      },
      {
        name: "React",
        dates: ["2017-05-25", "2017-05-26", "2017-05-27"],
        id: "2",
      },
      {
        name: "NodeJs",
        dates: ["2017-01-01", "2018-12-10", "2017-01-01", "2019-03-12"],
        id: "3",
      },
      {
        name: "AWS",
        dates: ["2017-01-01", "2017-10-31"],
        timestamp: "2012-04-23T07:22:43.511Z",

        id: "4",
      },
    ],
    selectedCourse: undefined,
  };

  onSelectCourse = (e) => {
    const selectedCourseId = e.target.value;

    if (selectedCourseId) {
      const selectedCourse = this.state.courses.find(
        (user) => user.id === selectedCourseId
      );
      this.setState({
        selectedCourse,
      });
    }
  };

  showUerData = () =>
    this.state.users.map((user, i) => <p key={i}>{user.name}</p>);

  render() {
    const { courses, selectedCourse } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <tr>
                <label>NAME*</label>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <select onChange={this.onSelectCourse}>
                  <option value="">Select</option>
                  {courses.map((item, i) => (
                    <option key={i} value={item.id}>
                      {item.name}
                    </option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </tr>
            </td>
            <td>
              <tr>
                <label>DATE</label>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <select>
                  <option value="">Select Date</option>
                  {selectedCourse?.dates.map((item) => (
                    <option key={item}>{item}</option>
                  ))}
                </select>
              </tr>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Just one more thing, please. Now selectedCourse stays undefined and it doesnt fill out the second select box. Any solution?

Comment: Is it happening with the above reference code?. We are retrieving  `selectedCourse` based on `id`, if no course is present you can make `selectedCourse=[]` or `undefined`.

Comment: thank you again! I just needed to do: parseInt(e.target.value). It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is

```
{
    this.state.selectedCourse.dates.map((item) =>
     <option key={item}>{item}</option>
    )
}
```

instead of

```
{this.state.selectedCourse.map((item) =>
  <option key={item}>{item}</option>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I get an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Your `this.state.selectedCourse` is just the name of the course, you have to set the whole object